# Cannot upload a Testflight version due to code signing errors

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Hello I am trying to upload a TestFlight version of the application and it cannot be done due to code signing issues. One of the errors is 'No code signing identities found - No valid signing identities matching the team ID'

I have contacted the team admin and recreated the provision profiles but nothing changed.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Are you using a beta version of Xcode?

Comment: No, I am using 7.2.1

Comment: Did you have the developer certificate too ? (well Distribution one for testflight) and did you renew your WWDR cert? https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Comment: Yes I renewed the WWDR and I have the developer cert. I don't have one for distribution

Comment: Tesflight builds must be signed Using a Production certificate. So you need a Distribution Certificate and the associated mobile provision